# Confused regarding this notation for scalar Xt?

Tags: martingales

[image: Question]

In the above, we are told that both |X<sub>t</sub><sup>$\preceq$</sup>| $\preceq$ |X<sub>t</sub>| and |X<sub>t</sub><sup>$\succ$</sup>| $\preceq$ |X<sub>t</sub>|.

Would appreciate clarification on 1) why this is the case, and 2) what the superscripts for |X<sub>t</sub><sup>$\preceq$</sup>| and |X<sub>t</sub><sup>$\succ$</sup>| are actually representing.

Comment: The definition of $X_t^{\leq}$ and $X_t^{>}$ is given in the second and fourth line, respectively. The claimed inequalities follow directly from this definition.

Answer (score 1):

This follows the fact that by definition 
$$\left|X_t^{\leq}  \right|=\left|X_t\mathbf 1_{\{ t\leqslant 100\}  }  \right|=\left|X_t    \right|\underbrace{\mathbf 1_{\{ t\leqslant 100\} }}_{\leqslant 1}\leqslant \left|X_t    \right|.$$
The other inequality can be proved in a completely similar way.